# Procedure opens multiple instances of Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I wrote the following procedure to check for Microsoft Excel application, if opened. The procedure works fine, except that once it opens the workbook and the activates the sheet, a second instance of Excel tries to open.

Here is my code:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWBName As String = "2011.1004.Compensation Template"

For Each p As System.Diagnostics.Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
    If p.ProcessName <> "EXCEL" Then
        xlApp.Visible = True
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Test Environment\Compensation Workbook\Compensation Workbook\bin\Debug\" & xlWBName & ".xlsx")
        Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        xlSheet = CType(xlBook.Sheets("SummaryWorksheet"), Worksheet)

        xlSheet.Activate()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you use the debugger to determine which line causes the second instance to open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `GetObject` method to find an already open Application object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863(v=vs.90).aspx

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

    Try
        'get an existing excel.application object
        xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Catch ex As Exception
        'no existing excel.application object - create a new one
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
    End Try

    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWBName As String = "2011.1004.Compensation Template"


    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Test Environment\Compensation Workbook\Compensation Workbook\bin\Debug\" & xlWBName & ".xlsx")
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    xlSheet = CType(xlBook.Sheets("SummaryWorksheet"), Worksheet)

    xlSheet.Activate()
```

Comment: Would it be better to catch the exact exception rather than assume any exception means that the application object did not exist?

Comment: The `GetObject` method has two exceptions -- one of type `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, and one of type `System.Exception`.  `FileNotFoundException` is raised when you specify an `appname` for parameter 1 of GetObject.  In this case, GetObject is not passing an `appname` parameter, and if `GetObject` fails, an exception of type `System.Exception` is returned.

Comment: Ah, right. I was thinking more along the lines of the `File` Class.

Comment: @mr.Reband Thanks, this worked great. One last thing, if when the procedure runs it detects that a workbook by the same name as the one being tested for is opened, can I have go to sheet1 of that open workbook?

Comment: @mr.Reband After some trials I was able to get it to work with the if condition.